# Installing PyQt 4.9 on CentOS 6.0 Fails

Tags: qt4, installation, python-3.x, pyqt4, python-sip

I'm totally fed up with this problem. I'm trying to install PyQt 4.9 on my server running on CentOS 6.0. When I install it, I get like this

```
[root@myserver PyQt]# python3 configure.py -k
Determining the layout of your Qt installation...
This is the GPL version of PyQt 4.9 (licensed under the GNU General Public
License) for Python 3.2.2 on linux2.

Type '2' to view the GPL v2 license.
Type '3' to view the GPL v3 license.
Type 'yes' to accept the terms of the license.
Type 'no' to decline the terms of the license.

Do you accept the terms of the license? yes
Found the license file pyqt-gpl.sip.
Checking to see if the QtGui module should be built...
Checking to see if the QtHelp module should be built...
Checking to see if the QtMultimedia module should be built...
Checking to see if the QtNetwork module should be built...
Checking to see if the QtDBus module should be built...
Checking to see if the QtDeclarative module should be built...
Checking to see if the QtOpenGL module should be built...
Checking to see if the QtScript module should be built...
Checking to see if the QtScriptTools module should be built...
Checking to see if the QtSql module should be built...
Checking to see if the QtSvg module should be built...
Checking to see if the QtTest module should be built...
Checking to see if the QtWebKit module should be built...
Checking to see if the QtXml module should be built...
Checking to see if the QtXmlPatterns module should be built...
Checking to see if the phonon module should be built...
Checking to see if the QtAssistant module should be built...
QtDesigner module disabled with static Qt libraries.
Checking to see if the dbus support module should be built...
DBus v1 does not seem to be installed.
Qt v4.6.2 free edition is being used.
SIP 4.13.1 is being used.
The Qt header files are in /usr/include.
The static Qt libraries are in /usr/lib.
The Qt binaries are in /usr/lib/qt4/bin.
The Qt mkspecs directory is in /usr/lib/qt4.
These PyQt modules will be built: QtCore, QtGui, QtHelp, QtMultimedia,
QtNetwork, QtDBus, QtOpenGL, QtScript, QtScriptTools, QtSql, QtSvg, QtTest,
QtXml, QtXmlPatterns, phonon, QtAssistant.
The PyQt Python package will be installed in
/usr/local/lib/python3.2/site-packages.
PyQt is being built with generated docstrings.
PyQt is being built with 'protected' redefined as 'public'.
The Designer plugin will be installed in /usr/lib/qt4/plugins/designer.
The PyQt .sip files will be installed in /usr/local/share/sip/PyQt4.
pyuic4, pyrcc4 and pylupdate4 will be installed in /usr/local/bin.
Generating the C++ source for the QtCore module...
Creating the Makefile for the QtCore module...
Generating the C++ source for the QtGui module...
Creating the Makefile for the QtGui module...
Generating the C++ source for the QtHelp module...
Creating the Makefile for the QtHelp module...
Generating the C++ source for the QtMultimedia module...
Creating the Makefile for the QtMultimedia module...
Generating the C++ source for the QtNetwork module...
Creating the Makefile for the QtNetwork module...
Generating the C++ source for the QtDBus module...
sip: QDBusPendingCall has not been defined
Error: Unable to create the C++ code.
```

I'm using

Python 3.2
sip 4.13
Qt 4.7.4 (4.8 RC)

Any help appreciated..

Thanks

Comment: Please run `python3 configure.py -w --confirm-license` and update your question with a copy of the full output.

Answer (score 3):

I encountered the same problem on CentOS5.3, and my Qt version is 4.2.1. After checking the code in pyqt4.9 (sip/QtDBus/qdbuspendingcall.sip)， I found it required the Qt 4.7.x, yet your qt version is 4.6.2. I upgraded my Qt and solved the problem. 
Hope it is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it's because your source code directory contains space (such as /Volumes/Macintosh HD/file ) and do not quoted by quotation marks cause shell parse failed.This is a bug.
You can place your code into /tmp to bypass this issue.