# Why PyQt 4.9 dont have WebKit

Tags: pyqt4, qtwebkit

I installed `Qt 4.8` which have the support of `QtWebkit`. After that i tried installing `PyQt-4.9`. on my `CentOS Server`. I dont understand why the `QtWebkit library` is not installed. The Source package does not contain the package at all.

Can any one help me finding a `PyQt` source with Webkit?..

Right now i cant do `from PyQt4.QtWebKit import QWebPage`

Comment: Did you check the documentation?

Comment: How did you install PyQt4? From CentOS packages, or compiled from source?

Comment: As with your [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8664863/984421) on this topic, please run `python3 configure.py -w --confirm-license` and update your question with a copy of the full output.

Answer (score -1):

try check you dev package of Qt4 on system.

i compile PyQt5 on Debian, but can find QtWebKit.
then i install `libqt5webkit5-dev` and compile PyQt5 again.

maybe helps.